# Query with date comparaison

Tags: laravel

I try to get the last recorded query from a table

the table could have two differents records but with the same id "`licencie_id`" , i would like to get only one record who find the **latest** record of `licencie_id` with a date "`dt_demande`" comparaison for exemple because i have a field '`dt_demande`' .

here my two records in the table :

```
id :46
licencie_id :36
dt_demande : 2017/03/23

id:50
licencie_id :36
dt_demande :2017/04/06
```

i would like to get id:50 because it's the lastest record from this licence.

here my actualy query who returns my the two records  :

`$demande = DemandeChangementClub::where('licencie_id' , $licencie->id)->where('dt_demande' , '<' , Carbon::now())->last();`

someone have an idea to get the latest record only ? thanks a lot in advance

Comment: you can try `...->whereRaw("DATE(dt_demandde) < '".\Carbon\Carbon::now()->toDateTimeString()."'")->last();`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can do something like this:

```
$demande = DemandeChangementClub::where('licencie_id' , $licencie->id) 

->orderBy('dt_demande', 'desc')->first();
```

or you can :

```
 $demande = DemandeChangementClub::where('licencie_id' , $licencie->id) 

 ->latest('dt_demande')->first();
```

Comment: love the second option ! it's working ! thanks so much